# Error message "unimplemented"

Tags: ocaml

I'm creating a recursive function to find m to the nth power without using **

```
let rec power m n = 
    match n with
    | 0 -> 1
    | _ -> m * (power m (n - 1));;

let test1 () : bool = (power 2 3) = 8;;
let test2 () : bool = (power 2 0) = 1;;
Assert.run_test "power test1" test1;;
Assert.run_test "power test2" test2;;
```

When I run the test I get an error message that says 
    Running: power test1 ... 
    Test error: `power test1` reported `power: unimplemented`

Comment: The answer seems to depend on details of the Assert module, which is possibly locally defined. OCaml has an `assert` construct, but no standard Assert module (that I know of).

Comment: Everything looks good in this code, maybe you have a stale version of power in your toplevel?? or maybe expecting test1 or test2 to be updated on a newer version of power added to the toplevel?